# Scala implicit class nested type parameter

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have implicit classes with nested type parameters to provide relevant methods to the data-object only when certain conditions are met and to store type information for later use. Somehow a nested type parameter only works with a wildcard but not with a type parameter. I do not understand why... 
The following piece of code works:

```
trait A
trait AB extends A
trait AC extends A

trait ByA[T, AX <: A]
case class ByAX[T, AX <: A]() extends ByA[T, AX]
case class Wrapper[T]()

implicit class WithByAB[T](tpe: Wrapper[_ <: ByA[T, AB]]) {
  def printsomething(): Unit = {
    println("WithByAB")
  }
}

Wrapper[ByAX[String, AB]]().printsomething()
//Wrapper[ByAX[String, AC]]().printsomething() does not compile (expected)
```

This one does not:

```
trait A
trait AB extends A
trait AC extends A

trait ByA[T, AX <: A]
case class ByAX[T, AX <: A]() extends ByA[T, AX]
case class Wrapper[T]()

implicit class WithByAB[T, S <: ByA[T, AB]](tpe: Wrapper[S]) {
  def printsomething(): Unit = {
    println("WithByAB")
  }
}

Wrapper[ByAX[String, AB]]().printsomething()
//Wrapper[ByAX[String, AC]]().printsomething() does not compile (expected)
```

It looks like the compiler cannot resolve type T but if the first example works and preserves the parameter-type information, why not in the second example?!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the scala compiler isn't able to deduce that `ByAX[String, AB]` actually conforms to `WithByAB[T, S <: ByA[T, AB]]`. It is unable to deduce that `T` conforms to `String` only from binding `S`.

We can see that when compiling with `-Xlog-implicits`:

```
λ scalac -Xlog-implicits Implicit.scala
Implicit.scala:22: WithByAB is not a valid implicit value for Wrapper[ByAX[String,AB]] => ?{def printsomething: ?} because:
inferred type arguments [Nothing,ByAX[String,AB]] do not conform to method WithByAB's type parameter bounds [T,S <: ByA[T,AB]]
    Wrapper[ByAX[String, AB]]().printsomething()
                             ^
Implicit.scala:22: error: value printsomething is not a member of Wrapper[ByAX[String,AB]]
    Wrapper[ByAX[String, AB]]().printsomething()
                                ^
one error found
```

Note how the compiler is unable to extract `String` from `ByAX` first type parameter. This is because from the compilers point of view, it has `S` which is bound by `ByAX`, but it is unaware of it's higher order or it's internal binding to `String`, all it can infer is a single type, merely `S`.

We can work around this by making `Wrapper` a bit more verbose

```
case class Wrapper[T, S]()

implicit class WithByAB[T, S <: ByA[T, AB]](tpe: Wrapper[T, S]) {
  def printsomething(): Unit = {
    println("WithByAB")
  }
}

Wrapper[String, ByAX[String, AB]]().printsomething()
```

Or, as you've noted, by making `Wrapper` bind to an existential.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yuval. I already went down the road of adding an extra parameter to the wrapper but I actually need the wrapper to also contain types without the sub-type T parameter. Hence I cannot store it explicitly inside the wrapper. So I guess I have to stick to my first example to match on subtypes of ByA and extract T without the ability to reuse the complete type.

Comment: @user3508638 If that works for you when using an existential, then go for it.